# How to access the String inside the List in Map<String, List<String>>?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dart-null-safety

```
final Map<String, List<String>> todoDate = {
'today': ['code', 'read a book']};
```

I am trying to display the String value in the List.

```
Text(todoDate['today'][0], //ERROR!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get null data while reading map. And Text widget doesn't accept null value. You can provide default value on null cases.

```
Text(todoDate['today']?[0]??"default");
```

Comment: Glad to help, Also beware of using !, without checking null. else it will raise on issue on null cases. You can test changing `'today'` with something else.

Comment: could you explain your code please? Thanks

Comment: Here if we encounter null value from `todoDate['today']?[0]` using ?? will return right part `default`, Check [this section](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [null assertion operator `!`](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator) to remove the null error.

It would be like this:

```dart
print(todoDate['today']![0]);
```

Just make sure the field exists otherwise you'd need to check if it's null first. And to check it you can use the [null aware operator `?`](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#smarter-null-aware-methods) in conjunction with the [null-coalescing operator `??`](https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety#null-aware-operators) to default it to something else instead.